# How to wrap Flutter provider around my flutter page to stop my state refreshing

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I add up values in by clicking a drawer route 1st shooter that routes to "first page" that has a counter in it:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fX33p.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgVRi.png)

But when i use the back button it clears the scores i know i need State management and i have installed provider to make the job easier. But what every i try to do with the State management code it doesn't like it. (wont wrap around my code i think?)

I have tried approaches like
class Counter with ChangeNotifier {

and notifyListeners();

but i cannot get it to wrap around my project

i have

1. main.dart
2. navbar.dart (has all routes to pages)
3. Eg 1st shooter on the navbar page routes to firstpage 2ndshooter routes to secondpage
4. i recon i need a provider.dart that adds up all the other shooters' scores and holds the data while navigating back and forth.
   im just having trouble wrapping the code around mine.
   this is the code if someone can please sugeusts where to add "provider code"

   main.dart

   ```
   import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
   import 'package:tca/navbar.dart';
   import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

   void main() {
     runApp(const MaterialApp(home: AddTwoNumbers()));
   }

   class AddTwoNumbers extends StatefulWidget {
     const AddTwoNumbers({super.key});

     @override
     State<AddTwoNumbers> createState() => _AddTwoNumbersState();
   }

   class _AddTwoNumbersState extends State<AddTwoNumbers> {
     List<TextEditingController> roundOneFields = [];
     List<TextEditingController> roundTwoFields = [];
     int roundOneResult = 0;
     int roundTwoResult = 0;

     @override
     void initState() {
       roundOneFields =
           List.generate(20, (index) => TextEditingController(text: '0'));
       roundTwoFields =
           List.generate(20, (index) => TextEditingController(text: '0'));
       super.initState();
     }

     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return Scaffold(
         appBar: AppBar(
           title: Text('Twin City Bowmen Score Sheet'),
           actions: <Widget>[
             IconButton(
               icon: const Icon(Icons.notifications),
               onPressed: () {},
             )
           ],
           backgroundColor: Colors.orangeAccent,
         ),
         drawer: Navbar(), // This is how you can add an appBar.
         body: SingleChildScrollView(
           child: Column(
             children: <Widget>[
               Row(
                 children: [
                   Expanded(
                     child: ListView.builder(
                       itemCount: 20,
                       shrinkWrap: true,
                       itemBuilder: (context, index) => Row(
                         children: <Widget>[
                           Text("R1 Target ${index + 1}:"),
                           Flexible(
                             child: TextField(
                               decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                   contentPadding:
                                       EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8)),
                               keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                               controller: roundOneFields[index],
                             ),
                           ),
                         ],
                       ),
                       physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                     ),
                   ),
                   const SizedBox(
                     width: 24,
                   ),
                   Expanded(
                     child: ListView.builder(
                       itemCount: 20,
                       shrinkWrap: true,
                       physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                       itemBuilder: (context, index) => Row(
                         children: <Widget>[
                           Text("R2 Target ${index + 1}:"),
                           Flexible(
                             child: TextField(
                               decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                   contentPadding:
                                       EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8)),
                               keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                               controller: roundTwoFields[index],
                             ),
                           ),
                         ],
                       ),
                     ),
                   ),
                 ],
               ),
               Row(
                 mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                 children: <Widget>[
                   ElevatedButton(
                     child: const Text("Add"),
                     onPressed: () {
                       setState(() {
                         roundOneFields.forEach((e) =>
                             roundOneResult = roundOneResult + int.parse(e.text));
                         roundTwoFields.forEach((e) => roundTwoResult =
                             roundTwoResult + int.parse(e.text.toString()));
                       });
                     },
                   )
                 ],
               ),
               Text(
                 "Result \n Round 1: $roundOneResult and Round 2: $roundTwoResult Total = ${roundOneResult + roundTwoResult}",
                 textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                 style: const TextStyle(
                   fontSize: 30,
                 ),
               ),
             ],
           ),
         ),
       );
     }
   }
   ```

   navbar.dart

   ```
   import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
   import 'package:tca/first_page.dart';
   import 'package:tca/pages/forth_page.dart';

   class Navbar extends StatelessWidget {
     const Navbar({super.key});

     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return Drawer(
         child: ListView(
           children: [
             UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
                 accountName: const Text('TCB'),
                 accountEmail: const Text('tcbowmen@gmail.com'),
                 currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
                     child:
                         ClipOval(child: Image.asset('lib/images/tcbicon.jpg'))),
                 decoration: BoxDecoration(
                   color: Colors.orangeAccent,
                 )),
             ListTile(
                 leading: Icon(Icons.file_upload),
                 title: Text('1st Shooter'),
                 onTap: () => Navigator.push(context,
                     MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AddTwoNumbers()))),
             ListTile(
               leading: Icon(Icons.card_membership),
               title: Text('2nd Shooter'),
               onTap: () => print('Member NO'),
             ),
             ListTile(
               leading: Icon(Icons.file_upload),
               title: Text('3rd Shooter'),
               onTap: () => print('Rules'),
             ),
             ListTile(
               leading: Icon(Icons.file_upload),
               title: Text('4th Shooter'),
               onTap: () => print('Rules'),
             ),
             ListTile(
                 leading: Icon(Icons.file_upload),
                 title: Text('5th Shooter'),
                 onTap: () => Navigator.push(context,
                     MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()))),
             ListTile(
               leading: Icon(Icons.file_upload),
               title: Text('6th Shooter'),
               onTap: () => print('Rules'),
             ),
             ListTile(
               leading: Icon(Icons.file_upload),
               title: Text('7th Shooter'),
               onTap: () => print('Rules'),
             ),
             ListTile(
               leading: Icon(Icons.file_upload),
               title: Text('8th Shooter'),
               onTap: () => print('Rules'),
             ),
           ],
         ),
       );
     }
   }
   ```

   ```
   // TODO Implement this library.
   import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
   import 'package:tca/navbar.dart';

   void main() {
     runApp(const MaterialApp(home: AddTwoNumbers()));
   }

   class AddTwoNumbers extends StatefulWidget {
     const AddTwoNumbers({super.key});

     @override
     State<AddTwoNumbers> createState() => _AddTwoNumbersState();
   }

   class _AddTwoNumbersState extends State<AddTwoNumbers>
       with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
     List<TextEditingController> roundOneFields = [];
     List<TextEditingController> roundTwoFields = [];
     int roundOneResult = 0;
     int roundTwoResult = 0;
     @override
     void initState() {
       roundOneFields =
           List.generate(20, (index) => TextEditingController(text: '0'));
       roundTwoFields =
           List.generate(20, (index) => TextEditingController(text: '0'));
       super.initState();
     }

     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       super.build(context);
       return Scaffold(
         appBar: AppBar(
           title: Text('Twin City Bowmen Score Sheet'),
           actions: <Widget>[
             IconButton(
               icon: const Icon(Icons.notifications),
               onPressed: () {},
             )
           ],
           backgroundColor: Colors.orangeAccent,
           leading: IconButton(
             icon: const Icon(Icons.menu),
             onPressed: () {},
           ),
           shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
               borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                   bottomLeft: Radius.circular(25),
                   bottomRight: Radius.circular(25))),
         ), // This is how you can add an appBar.
         body: SingleChildScrollView(
           child: Column(
             children: <Widget>[
               Row(
                 children: [
                   Expanded(
                     child: ListView.builder(
                       itemCount: 20,
                       shrinkWrap: true,
                       itemBuilder: (context, index) => Row(
                         children: <Widget>[
                           Text("R1 Target ${index + 1}:"),
                           Flexible(
                             child: TextField(
                               decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                   contentPadding:
                                       EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8)),
                               keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                               controller: roundOneFields[index],
                             ),
                           ),
                         ],
                       ),
                       physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                     ),
                   ),
                   const SizedBox(
                     width: 24,
                   ),
                   Expanded(
                     child: ListView.builder(
                       itemCount: 20,
                       shrinkWrap: true,
                       physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                       itemBuilder: (context, index) => Row(
                         children: <Widget>[
                           Text("R2 Target ${index + 1}:"),
                           Flexible(
                             child: TextField(
                               decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                   contentPadding:
                                       EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8)),
                               keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                               controller: roundTwoFields[index],
                             ),
                           ),
                         ],
                       ),
                     ),
                   ),
                 ],
               ),
               Row(
                 mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                 children: <Widget>[
                   ElevatedButton(
                     child: const Text("Add"),
                     onPressed: () {
                       setState(() {
                         roundOneFields.forEach((e) =>
                             roundOneResult = roundOneResult + int.parse(e.text));
                         roundTwoFields.forEach((e) => roundTwoResult =
                             roundTwoResult + int.parse(e.text.toString()));
                       });
                     },
                   )
                 ],
               ),
               Row(
                 mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                 children: <Widget>[
                   ElevatedButton(
                       child: const Text("Back"),
                       onPressed: () => Navigator.push(context,
                           MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Navbar())))
                 ],
               ),
               Text(
                 "Result \n Round 1: $roundOneResult and Round 2: $roundTwoResult Total = ${roundOneResult + roundTwoResult}",
                 textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                 style: const TextStyle(
                   fontSize: 30,
                 ),
               ),
             ],
           ),
         ),
       );
     }

     @override
     bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
   }
   ```